# postgres - ERROR: syntax error at or near "COST"

Tags: postgresql, function

***EDIT* Taking COST 100 out made the command go through, however, I'm still unable to run my query because it yields this error:**

```
ERROR:  function group_concat(character) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.
```

The query I'm running is this:

```
select tpid, group_concat(z) as z,                                                                                                                                                    
    group_concat(cast(r as char(2))) as r,                                                                                                                                   
    group_concat(to_char(datecreated,'DD-Mon-YYYY HH12:MI am')) as datecreated,                                                                                                        
    group_concat(to_char(datemodified,'DD-Mon-YYYY HH12:MI am')) as datemodified                                                                                                       
    from tpids group by tpid order by tpid, zip
```

This function seems to work fine locally, but moving it online yields this error...  Is there something I'm missing?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION group_concat(text, text)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
SELECT CASE
WHEN $2 IS NULL THEN $1
WHEN $1 IS NULL THEN $2
ELSE $1 operator(pg_catalog.||) ',' operator(pg_catalog.||) $2
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE 'sql' IMMUTABLE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION group_concat(text, text) OWNER TO j76dd3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the hint message states, you are missing an argument to your stored procedure. It expects 2 arguments, but in your column statments:

```
group_concat(cast(r as char(2))) as r,
group_concat(to_char(datecreated,'DD-Mon-YYYY HH12:MI am')) as datecreated,
group_concat(to_char(datemodified,'DD-Mon-YYYY HH12:MI am')) as datemodified
```

you supply only one.

Since PostgreSQL 8.4 default values for arguments are allowed. Take a look at the [reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-PARAMETER-DEFAULTS) for more information and examples.